# Impact on policy after deleting IAM user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-iam

I have created one IAM User named "test" with S3 and Glacier Permission.

Now with user "test" i created one life cycle policy to move data from S3 to Glacier at every 5 days.

Now, i delete IAM user "test" because i don't need it anymore.

So my question here is, After deleting user "test", S3 Life cycle policy will work or not? OR will there be any impact on life cycle policy?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> S3 Life cycle policy will remain and working as it is.

When you use the AWS Management Console to delete an IAM user, IAM automatically deletes the following information for user:

- The user Any group memberships.
- The user is removed from any IAM groups.
- That the user was a member of Any password associated with the user
- Any access keys belonging to the user.
- All inline policies embedded in the user (policies that are applied
  to a user via group permissions are not affected)

Answer (score 4):

The policy will still exist.

The [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_users_manage.html#id_users_deleting) lists what is deleted when a user is deleted, any resources that the user has created will persist.